# Socket.io keeps sending message to all client even client that has not joined room

Tags: socket.io

Here is the issue. I press button on client 1 then client 2. no data is passed as expected. Now lets say that client 1 press button to join room. Data is then passed however client 2 can still get the data and it has not joined the room

server

```
 // join room
    socket.on("join", (roomName, data) => {
      socket.join(roomName);
      console.log("user has join", { roomName, socket: socket.id });
    });

    // send message
    socket.on("send_message", (roomName, sender, data) => {
      io.in(roomName).emit("new_message", { sender, data });
      console.log(
        "receive a message here but need to be in joined to see it",
        roomName
      );
    });
```

client

```
 mySocket.on('new_message', data => {
      console.log('here is the data from room', data);
    });

 <Button
          style={{margin: 10}}
          title="join abc room"
          onPress={() => mySocket.emit('join', 'abc')}
        />
        
        <Button
          title="Send a message abc" //roomName, sender, data
          style={{margin: 10}}
          onPress={() =>
            mySocket.emit(
              'send_message',
              'abc',
              firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
              'hello',
            )
          }
        />
```

How do I fix this so that only clients that have joined receive messages

Comment: did you find any solution to this...

Comment: i am also having trouble... whenever i create dynamic rooms it auto send it to the clients which haven't joined yet...